# Does Windows Phone 7 OS support Sampling frequency of 44.1 kHz?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I would like to know whether Windows Phone 7 OS supports Sampling frequency of 44.1 kHz, while recording the audio?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, I am trying to record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microphone's sample rate is [fixed at 16KHz](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598930.aspx).

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can't I change it to 44.1 kHz while recording. I am able to set the sampling frequency of 44.1 kHz for iPhone and Android.

Comment: @RaviTeja I was going by what I read in Petzold's article. But according to MSDN the [Microphone.SampleRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone.samplerate.aspx) property doesn't have a setter.

Comment: Yes, I have also found the same, no setter, thanks - I will mark this as solution.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention in what context (record? playback?), but generally speaking the minimum requirements for Windows Phone says [maximum 48kHz sample rate on the audio Codec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

So, yes, it supports 44.1 kHz sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is misleading -- the 16 kHz sample rate is a limitation of the particular XNA Microphone class used in the sample and not a limitation of the OS.

By extending the AudioSink class you are able to access audio at higher sampling rates:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.audiosink(v=vs.95).aspx